# Unable to add custom list view of standard object in managed package

Tags: lightning, managed-package, lightning-experience, event

I want to include the custom list view (Created in lightning experience only) of Event object in the managed package. I have added the custom list view of Event object in a package and the list view is shown in the package list components. But, it does not present if I open the specific latest released version.

[image]

Fig 1- Package components
  Child Event List view is the list view that I have added in the package. But, it doesn't have any link.

[image]

Fig 2- Specific version package components.
   List view is not present under the resources tab.
Note- List view components are shown under the resources tab only.

Is there any way to add the custom list view created in lightning experience for the Event object in the managed package?

Answer (score 1):

'Custom list views for standard objects aren’t included as dependencies, although custom list views for custom objects are included.' https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_export_considerations.htm&type=5